# dataclass json for python make optional attribute

Tags: python

Having this dataclass wish to be reuse in 2 different scenario

```
class TestResponse:
    name: str
    parameters: Optional[list[ActionParameters]]
```

when call it with

```
TestResponse(
            name=name,
        )
```

without adding parameter attribute, will hit an error. how to make this attribute to be something like optional?

Comment: As per the answer in the linked thread, just define a valid default value, e.g. `parameters: Optional[...] = None`

Comment: Is there a difference between `parameters = None` and `parameters = []`?